Wix forms CORS issue
I am trying to submit a service call request using Wix Forms. The request works perfectly on Postman, but it fails when using Wix Forms, showing a CORS policy error.
Backend Code (backend/formHandler.jsw):
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

export function submitServiceCallBackend(formData) {
const url = "https://80.81.34.29:9554/api/ServiceCalls/ServiceCallAdd";

    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify(formData);
    
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: body
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        throw error;
    });

}

Frontend Code:
import { submitServiceCallBackend } from 'backend/formHandler';

$w.onReady(function () { $w('#submitButton').onClick(() => { const formData = { Token: "TestServiceCall", LicTradNum: $w('#license').value, Subject: $w('#subject').value, Description: $w('#description').value, ContactPersonEmail: $w('#email').value, ContactPersonName: $w('#name').value, ContactPersonPhone: $w('#phone').value };
submitServiceCallBackend(formData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Success:', response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
});
});

Error Messages:
Console:

Access to fetch at 'https://editor.wix.com/html/editor/web/renderer/render/document/9723edf9-4a0c-4251-828a-bd598d31a532/_api/wix-forms/v1/submit-form' from origin 'https://b46f501b-56da-4e23-aeb9-a02a6b083b93.dev.wix-code.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://editor.wix.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Wix console:

Network response was not ok Forbidden

What I've Tried:

The API request works fine on Postman.
The error occurs when using Wix Forms due to CORS policy issues.
Question:
How can I resolve this CORS policy issue and successfully submit the form data using Wix Forms? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.


CORS policy is a security feature implemented by the browser to prevent unauthorized access to resources from different origins. This is why you won't face CORS errors in Postman.
Before the POST request is sent by the browser, a preflight (OPTIONS) request is made. This request must be handled by the server and the response must contain an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. This header should also be included in the response to your actual POST request. You can read more about this header online.
As a simple workaround you can configure the server to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with a wildcard value (*), which allows requests from any origin (although not recommended as it defeats the purpose of CORS policies).
Depending on the tech stack you've used to build your server, there would be many libraries that can help you handle CORS and set the appropriate headers.
